# How can i get a Text in a Chat Bubble?

Tags: html, text, chat

I want my entered text to appear in the Bubble. How do I have to change my code to make it work?

My HTML Code is this One:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<div class="Webview">

  <div class="message_container" id="myForm">
    <div class="Chat_Bubble"></div>
  </div>

  <form class="send_container">
    <input id="textField" type="text">
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Nachricht absenden!" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML=document.getElementById('Chat_Bubble').value.innerHTML=document.getElementById('textField').value" />
    </p>
    <h3>
      <div id="div"></div>
    </h3>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to both set `myForm.innerHTML` *and* `Chat_Bubble.innerHTML`.** You can use:

1. `document.getElementById('myForm').children[0].innerHTML = (...)`, or
2. `document.getElementsByClassName('Chat_Bubble').innerHTML = (...)`. You need to get the element using the class name, because the `div` has a `class`, not an `id`.

Also, it's good practice to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. This way you're sure that the element submitted is seen as text by the browser. Using `innerHTML` anyway can break your page. I changed this in the code below.

For example, you should try submitting `<b>` (nothing is drawn on the screen).

**The following code works:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<div class="Webview">

  <div class="message_container" id="myForm">
    <div class="Chat_Bubble"></div>
  </div>

  <form class="send_container">
    <input id="textField" type="text">
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Nachricht absenden!" onclick=" document.getElementsByClassName('Chat_Bubble')[0].textContent = document.getElementById('textField').value" />
    </p>
    <h3>
      <div id="div"></div>
    </h3>
  </form>
</div>
```